# Calendar strip is not behaving as it should

Tags: react-native, calendar

I'm using [`react-native-calendar-strip`](https://github.com/BugiDev/react-native-calendar-strip) to create a calendar.

[Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@brej/anxious-truffles) my code.

My goal is to have on the "first line" a component like this:

```
< month name of the days showed in the strip >
```

If user tap on the left arrow (`<`), the strip should "go back" and show the week containing the first day of the previous month.
If user tap on the right arrow (`>`), the strip should "move on" and show the week containing the first day of the next month.

Example: today is the 4 sept.
the shown week is the current one: 30 aug - 5 sept. the selected date is 4 sept.

- tap on the right arrow --> the shown week is the current one: 27 sept - 3 oct. the selected date is always 4 sept.
- tap on the left arrow --> the shown week is the current one: 26 jul - 1 aug. the selected date is always 4 sept.

This is exactly the Google Calendar behaviour.

On the right there is the `Today` button, if user tap on that button, the selected date become today.

On the "second line" there is the calendar strip built by `react-native-calendar-strip`.
It should be scrollable, and the shown week should start always on Monday.
When user tap on a day, that day become selected (is pass to became black from gray), and the shown week shouldn't change. The selected day does not always have to be in the center, it has to remain in its original position. It changes only the color.
Today's day should always be red unless selected. In that case it goes back to the previous case and it would turn black.

When the shown week changes, the app should download new data (the ones in that range).

I used the library in that way:

```js
<CalendarStrip
  ref={dateStripRef}
  scrollable={true}
  scrollerPaging={true}
  startingDate={startingDate}
  useIsoWeekday={true}
  selectedDate={moment(today)}
  onDateSelected={(date) =>
    setSelectedDateString(date.format(DATE_FORMAT))
  }
  scrollToOnSetSelectedDate={false}
  onWeekChanged={(start, end) => {
    setVisibleWeekRange([
      start.format(DATE_FORMAT),
      // FIXME: on mount "end" is saturday, not sunday!
      end.format(DATE_FORMAT),
    ]);
  }}
  style={{ height: STRIP_HEIGHT }}
  calendarColor="white"
  styleWeekend={false}
  upperCaseDays={false}
  customDatesStyles={(date) => {
    const isToday =
      today.format(DATE_FORMAT) === moment(date).format(DATE_FORMAT);
    if (isToday) {
      return {
        dateNameStyle: { color: 'red', ...DATES_STYLE },
        dateNumberStyle: { color: 'red', ...DATES_STYLE },
      };
    }
  }}
  dateNameStyle={{ color: 'gray', ...DATES_STYLE }}
  dateNumberStyle={{ color: 'gray', ...DATES_STYLE }}
  highlightDateNameStyle={{
    color: 'black',
    ...DATES_STYLE,
    fontWeight: '700',
  }}
  highlightDateNumberStyle={{
    color: 'black',
    ...DATES_STYLE,
    fontWeight: '700',
  }}
  markedDates={data.map((r) => ({
    date: moment(r[0]),
    dots: [{ color: 'red' }],
  }))}
  markedDatesStyle={{
    width: 5,
    height: 5,
    borderRadius: 2.5,
  }}
  leftSelector={[]}
  rightSelector={[]}
  showMonth={false}
/>
```

If you tested it, you can note some problems:

- if you tap on a day, that day is not selected (it seems like there is a rerender)
- today is not red
- the first line buttons do not work (today button and <, > buttons)

I read the library documentation several times but I'm not able to make it work as I would.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: You advertise your question with `200` bounties, but my friend, you should add more detail to help visitors to completely understand your situation. About something like your question even details aren't enough, you should add reproduction of your issue on [snack.expo.dev/](https://snack.expo.dev/). Then visitors can easily access to your issue, By current situation, no one have this time to reproduce your issue. I want to help you. please make your SNACK and mention me, I will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 concerns here: showing a specific week and selecting a date, you use 2 different states to handle each.

```
  const [selectedDateString, setSelectedDateString] = useState(todayFormatted);
  const [currenDateVisible, setCurrentDateVisible] = useState(todayFormatted);
```

you update both when selecting a date as in `selectToday` event

```
        selectToday={() => {
          setSelectedDateString(todayFormatted);
          setCurrentDateVisible(todayFormatted);
        }}
```

and `onDateSelected`

```
        onDateSelected={(date) => {
          setSelectedDateString(date.format(DATE_FORMAT));
          setCurrentDateVisible(date.format(DATE_FORMAT));
        }}
```

when you want to move the visible week, you update only the `currenDateVisible` state, as in move prev and next month

```
        onPrevMonth={() => {
          setCurrentDateVisible((currentDateString) => {
            return moment(currentDateString)
                    .subtract(1,'months')
                    .startOf('month')
                    .format(DATE_FORMAT);
          })
        }}
        onNextMonth={() => {
          setCurrentDateVisible((currentDateString) => {
            const nextMonthFirstDay = moment(currentDateString)
                    .add(1,'months')
                    .startOf('month')
                    .format(DATE_FORMAT);
            return nextMonthFirstDay;
          })
        }}
```

as for the red color, I think it's working as you have it, just change the order to ensure the color red is the last to be applied and add `highlightDateNumberStyle` to force back the color to black when today is selected.

```
            return {
              dateNameStyle: { ...DATES_STYLE, color: 'red', },
              dateNumberStyle: { ...DATES_STYLE, color: 'red' },
              highlightDateNumberStyle: { ...DATES_STYLE, color: 'black' },
            };
```

this is my snack with all these updates https://snack.expo.dev/@diedu89/react-native-calendar-strip-

**Note**: I had to fix the version of `react-native-calendar-strip` to `2.2.0` because the latest release has the `scrollToIndex` [bug](https://github.com/BugiDev/react-native-calendar-strip/issues/306)